How to download the datasets from mlflow.log_input?
In Mlflow when you use mlflow.log_input in the UI I can see the dataset hyperlinks (blue texts) for different datasets however, when I press on it, it only shows the info like metadata of the dataset.

I would imagine there is a download button or somethin similar, after following the hyperlink - how to download data for the 4 dataset?

